# Articulate Storyline & tabletop.js

Tags: articulate-storyline, tabletop.js

Been trying for hours how to get this `for` loop to work.  Using Tabletop to get info from Google sheet which is working fine when used like this:

```
function showInfo(data) {
    var player = GetPlayer();
    player.SetVar("score", data[0].name);
}
```

`GetPlayer()` is default Articualte Storyline function which is assigned to a variable `player`.  I try adding a for loop and the code no longer works.

Here is the code with the `for` loop added:

```
function showInfo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var player = GetPlayer();
        player.SetVar("name", data[i].name);
    }
}
```

Finally the whole Javascript code being used in the trigger:

```
var public_spreadsheet_url = 'http://foo.com';

Tabletop.init({
    key: public_spreadsheet_url,
    callback: showInfo,
    prettyColumnNames: false
});

function showInfo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var player = GetPlayer();
        player.SetVar("name", data[i].name);
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors? How is it not working?